# One menu bar for multiple page in html

Tags: html, css

I am creating a html page for the school project **course registration system** I am creating a home page with **dropdown menu bar** I want it the same menu bar is displayed on each page. I trying to understand with the help of **templates** but I can't understand how can I use it after that I searched use php line  to add in html page
but I am confused is it I need to edit the whole html code in php code so help me to figure out this problem because I don't know how to code in php...

here is the code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRTS8.png)

and the page looks like[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el1nm.png)

Comment: Do you want to have same nav bar for all your pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use php `include` and `require` they are used to include and load snippets of codes in any section of your html page, in your case just put your navbar code into a seperate php file and then include it at the top of any page you want to have it

```
<?php include('navbar.php') ?>
//rest of your page
```

`include` means that the page will still load if for some reason the `navbar.php` file dosen't load

But if you want the page not to load without loading the `navbar`, then use require. this will be ideal if you make a database connection in your `navbar` file (ideally you shouldn't do that though). but it's just there if you require some assets or file to load completely before loading the main page

```
<?php require('navbar.php') ?>
```

check this out http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

Comment: In current page I have to save page by .php extension or it will work in .html page

Comment: use `.php` since it can contain just static html